# Fetching tables from BigQuery using Service Account in JSON format

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to fetch tables from a dataset using a service account in JSON format.

I have got the list of datasets from one project using the following code snippet:

```
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(path)

datasets = list(client.list_datsets())
```

Now I need the list of all tables from any particular dataset.

I do not have IAM rights.

Therefore I'm using a service account.

Comment: what the question is really? if you got to the point of getting list of datasets - what potentially the issue you have with getting tables list? give us your actual problem so we can help :o)

Comment: list(client.list_datsets(client.dataset(dataset_id))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand what you mean when you say you use Service Account credentials because you do not have IAM rights. But I presume that you have a JSON-encoded key for a Service Account with the right permissions to access the data that you want to retrieve.

As of writing, the latest version of the [BigQuery Python Client Library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-bigquery) `google.cloud.bigquery` is `0.32.0`. In this version of the library, you can use the `list_tables()` function to list the tables in a given dataset. To do so, you will have to pass as an argument to that function the reference to a dataset. Below I share a small code example that lists the datasets (and their nested tables) for the project to which the Service Account in use has access:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json("/path/to/key.json")

for dataset in client.list_datasets():
    print(" - {}".format(dataset.dataset_id))

    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset.dataset_id)
    for table in client.list_tables(dataset_ref):
        print("   - {}".format(table.table_id))
```

The output is something like:

```
 - dataset1
   - table1
   - table2
 - dataset2
   - table1
```

You can find more information about the [Dataset class](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/reference.html#google.cloud.bigquery.dataset.Dataset) and the [Table class](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/reference.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table) in the documentation too. Also here you have the [general page of the documentation for the BigQuery Python Client Library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#).